# Any suggestions on how to scale a full screen iPad image without losing image quality?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, scale

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Full screen image of an animal (vector based art, not a photo) on an iPad. When you click on a body part, let's say the ear, the image zooms and recenters on the ear and text is displayed about the ear. Click the zoom out button and you're back to the full body shot. I know how to program the zooming and moving, but I don't know what the best approach would be for handling the image quality. The 1024x768 image needs to zoom by 400% to get the crop effect that I want. Obviously, for the new iPad, that 1024x768 image would already start doubled and have to increase 400% from there.

The initial inclination is to take a 4096x3072 image and start with it scaled down to 1/4, then when you scale in 400%, you don't lose image quality. This one image uses almost 70MB of memory which is expected and I understand why that's happening, but obviously that's not going to fly when this is only one part of a larger app. Let alone what would happen with an @2x version for retina.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this effect without putting such a load on the device? It looks like iOS devices can't work with vector images, only rasterized ones. Because of the level of detail I'd like to achieve, I can't just zoom in and deal with the loss of quality. Is this even doable or should I find a different approach? I am working with XCode 4.3.1 and Cocos2d v 1.0.1, but can look into v2.0 if that would solve my problem.

Full body image of my super awesome lemur (I have a graphic designer to do this later):
[image]

Zoomed in on the ear:

[image]

Once our designer works on it, I imagine something more along these lines (image from google images search, not my work, and hopefully ours won't be so grumpy):

[image]

Comment: HD lemurs is exactly what the humanity needs! I finally found someone who shares the same thought

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337870/is-it-possible-to-tile-images-in-a-uiscrollview-without-having-to-manually-creat. There's also a link to PhotoScroller sample code that contains image-tiling example. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Keep in mind that the maximum texture size on iPad 1 is 2048x2048. Only the latest iPad (3) supports texture sizes of up to 4096x4096, the iPad 2 only supports 4096x4096 with iOS 5.1 installed, otherwise it's 2048x2048 as well.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yeah I forgot to mention that in my post. Thanks for pointing that out! Currently, this is for internal use at a museum and I'll be able to design more specifically for the iPad 2's and "3's". This size constraint doesn't affect me specifically, but will affect others looking at this post as a reference. Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use multiple images. Have a full-screen completely zoomed-out image. When the user decides to zoom in on some part then display another full-screen image of the zoomed-in part. You can animation the transition (fade in/out) such that it will be sufficiently smooth.

This assumes finite zooming options. For example the user can zoom into n difference places on the animal.

Comment: Yeah that was an approach I was looking at, however the ideal end goal is that the whole body zooms. Plan B is to do this and flash a border around the body part then zoom that individual image.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could tweak the animation s.t. the "before" image (whole body when zooming in) would slowly fade out + zoom... hence approximating the desired effect.

Comment: Because our design department also wants the individual body parts to be animated, such as blinking eyes, twitching ears, etc.; I'm going to take this approach. Creating each body part and puzzle-piecing them back together is something I'm more comfortable with and can acheive faster than the SVG approach suggested by Mark below. But SVG is definitely worth checking out if you work with a lot of vector art or have a strong vector art background.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is vector graphics can't you just calculate the needed sub-image on the fly?

That will give you the best quality and you don't have to worry about massive 4X images or minification artifacts.

This article should help: http://rdsquared.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/svg-to-coregraphics-conversion/

If you're not using SVG, then maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: I'd read a little about people using SVG, but it certainly seems complicated. That's a well written article and I'll check out the process when I'm back at my work computer. I've added a new image to the original question that's a bit closer to the art style. In your opinion, would the SVG approach work with more complicated artwork like this? What I gathered from skimming through is that the SVG approach works for single objects, not necessarily characters made of dozens of objects. But maybe his example was just a very basic intro to the concept. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes I think that this technique could work depending on how often you need to re-render the SVG. You could use a cache technique that keeps any rendered images around and dump them if memory gets low. This may be a bit more complicated than just loading pre-rendered textures, but you're trading space on the device for compute time. Another technique that Apple recommends, if you are using OpenGL, is to use PVRTC textures as described here<http://j.mp/AiYgNP> (Sorry for the URL shortener). That way the textures are stored compressed on the video card. But PVRTC textures need to be pre-rendered.

Comment: PVRTC seems like a valid approach, however even Apple says this may not work on future devices and encourages using an uncompressed format as a stand-by. SVG looks like a much better approach to this problem than PVRTC, but with how much time it will take to accomplish this correctly, I don't think there's enough ROI. I will certainly keep this in mind for future artwork. If anyone else is interested in the SVG approach, try this project complete with working samples for animation, but scaling doesn't work as nicely as I'd like: https://github.com/reklis/SVGKit/

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion: use Quartz 2d CGContextRef

1) Save your graphics as PDF. it would be small as it's vector

2) Open the PDF as described here:[Quartz 2D Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101)

3) create CGBitmapContext and render needed part of pdf there

4) create CCTexture2D from CGBitmapContext - take a look here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/30152?replies=6#post-148782 or examine CCTexture2D.m -initWithImage

5) use it.

Comment: @BobbyScon: actually I solved your task as described in my suggestion - it was a side effect of my current project. Full-screen sprite from PDF loads on iPad 2 for 25ms and eats 120kb on disk. The same picture  exported to PNG loads for 77 ms. Sprite from PDF can be easily scaled to any size without any problems. I will create a fully-working extension for Cocos2d in a while, so check here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/30152.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [CGContextScaleCTM](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextScaleCTM) function in the Quartz 2D framework to scale the high resolution images smoothly.

You can find a nice sample application by Apple in url mentioned below.
[MoveMe_APLMoveMeView_m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html)

## TiledImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TiledImageView : UIView {
    CGFloat imageScale;
    UIImage* image;
    CGRect imageRect;
}
@property (retain) UIImage* image;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)_frame image:(UIImage*)_image scale:(CGFloat)_scale;

@end
```

## TiledImageView.m

```
#import "TiledImageView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation TiledImageView

@synthesize image;

// Set the layer's class to be CATiledLayer.
+ (Class)layerClass {
    Return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [image release];
    //--
    [super dealloc];
}

// Create a new TiledImageView with the desired frame and scale.
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)_frame image:(UIImage*)_image scale:(CGFloat)_scale {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:_frame])) {
        self.image = _image;
        imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage), CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage));
        imageScale = _scale;
        CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
        // levelsOfDetail and levelsOfDetailBias determine how
        // the layer is rendered at different zoom levels.  This
        // only matters while the view is zooming, since once the 
        // the view is done zooming a new TiledImageView is created
        // at the correct size and scale.
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 4;
        tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(512.0, 512.0); 
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)_rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    // Scale the context so that the image is rendered 
    // at the correct size for the zoom level.
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, imageScale,imageScale);  
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);    
}
@end
```